# PHP MVC - does the label string become part of the model instead of view when it changes with the object type?

Tags: php, oop, templates

I have a "summery" view for an Iterated list of polymorphic objects, and I experimenting with a clean separation of the view and the model.

So, where do I put the static label information?  I am trying to avoid this sort of thing in the view...

```
while loop do
  switch (prop->type)
    case foo:
      echo "label1: ". prop->data1;
      echo "label2: ". prop->data2;
    break;
    case bar:
      echo "label3: ". prop->data1;
      echo "label2: ". prop->data2;
      ...
```

This can make the view code pretty messy, especially when you have up to 10 different prop->type and the summery has to be shown in several different areas.

I guess the real question here is...has the label ceased to be part of the view and now is part of the model because it changes dynamically depending on the object type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a switch statement isn't probably the best practice here. Everytime you need a new type you would have to add a new case. It would be better to store the corresponding labels along with the data in your class in my opinion. But let's tackle the problem.

## [Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)

One thing you can do is to implement a [Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) for your `prop` class that adds a functionality to get the corresponding Label.

```
class PrintLabelPropDecorator {

    protected $prop;

    public function __construct(Prop $prop)
    {
        $this->prop = $prop;
    }

    public function printLabels()
    {
        switch($this->prop->type)
        {
            case 'foo':
                echo 'Label1: ' . $this->prop->data1;
                echo 'Label2: ' . $this->prop->data2;
            break; 

            //[...]
        }
    }

}
```

The first thing we do is to inject the class we want to decorate into the constructor.
Then we write the actual decoration method `printLabels()`. That does the actual check and prints the label information.

Now we only need to decorate the actual class. For simplification reasons I do this in a pseudo-controller method. You should outsource it by your demands.

```
<?php
public function myControllerMethod()
{
    //$props = whatever you need to do to get the prop objects

    $printLabelPropDecorators = [];

    // That should usually better not be handled by the controller
    foreach($props AS $prop)
    {
        $printLabelPropDecorators[] = new PrintLabelPropDecorator($prop);
    }

    $this->view->create('myfancyview', compact('printLabelPropDecorators'));

}
```

We create an array that will hold our decorated objects and then iterate trough the base objects and create our decorator objects. Then we simply pass the array with our decorators to the view. (The decoration process is not quite elegant, you could for example write some kind of Collection for this).

Now the only thing left to do is the view. It should be self explanatory:

```
<?php foreach($printLabelPropDecorators AS $prop): ?>

    <?php $prop->printLabels(); ?>

<?php endforeach ?>
```

That could be one approach to do it. The actual logic that decides which labels to print does now live in the Decorator and you are not cluttering your view.

Comment: very interesting...so the Decorator class is part of the model called in the controller and passed to the view.  What about the idea of using polymorphism in the data/model class and define the printLabels() there?  And perhaps, since all ['code'](prop) model/data objects

Comment: When speaking in terms of MVC, you could speak of this decorator as "View Presenter". Well, it's neither a pure Model (presenting stuff is normally not handled by the model layer) nor a pure View (normally the view layer should not contain any logic).

Comment: very interesting...so the Decorator class is part of the model called in the controller and passed to the view.  What about the idea of using polymorphism in the data/model class and define the printLabels() there?  And perhaps, since all `prop` model/data objects need to be able, in my app, to describe their own summary, it could be added to the `interface`?

Comment: That would theoretically be possible but you would violate the purpose of the model layer. Your entity should hold and provide your data but outputting anything should not be part of it. So I would advise against it.